# My Postgres database didnt hold my last db changes?

Tags: php, postgresql, pgadmin

I am using postgre db for my php project, when I just create a new database or coloum in existing db. It will not show in the next system start. I am currently doing a GIS app, so I installed opengeosuite software. And the pgAdmin was from this software. Is it make any problem?

Please help..

Comment: Do you have autocommit turned off?

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: How about data changes ? does it persist on next system start ?

Comment: no,newly added data or coloumn doesn't persist on next system start.

Comment: on psql, try "show fsync". If fsync is off, that could be the cause.

Comment: No,I checked; Its on.

Comment: fsync is at filesystem level, try with show autocommit if you use a 9.2 or a higher version, do you verify that the statement not trhow any error?

Comment: your statements are not executing successfully. These should persist as they are schema level changes. Are you getting any errors when you add columns ? can you query the columns when you have added them ?

Comment: no , I can add columns